# Getting Selected value on Dropdown - MySQL , PHP , HTML

Tags: php, mysql

Its my first steps on HTML and PHP . Im trying to create a dropdown box populated by MYSQL database.

In my code i can see the options but i want to get selected item via submit button or ONCHANGE function but i dont know how to do that.

Tried to search google for 5 hours. Im just an idiot or blind but can you help me ?

Here is my code :

```
<form>    
  <select id="choosePatient" name="PatientBox">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose</option>

    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>

    <option value="<?= $user['patient_id']; ?>">
      <?= $user['name']; ?>
        <?= 
                      $user['surname']; ?>
    </option>


    <?php endforeach; ?>

  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided detail isn't enough, however I've put together the following snippet for you to get some idea.

```js
$("#choosePatient").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    alert("You have selected the patient - " + selectedCountry);
});

$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedCountry = $('#choosePatient').children("option:selected").val();
    alert("You have selected the patient - " + selectedCountry);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>  
  <select id="choosePatient" name="PatientBox">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose</option>   
    <option value="1">User 1</option>
    <option value="2">User 2</option>
    <option value="3">User 3</option>
    <option value="4">User 4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thats really what i wanted to do. I thought the things can go crazy when populating dropdown from mysql but it was so simple like you wrote. I didn't know that i can get values by JS too.


Thanks a lot man <3